# How to invert or filter out the two employees that work on projects in other departments?

Tags: mysql, sql

So right now I am so close but right now the result table that is return only shows the employees that I don't want to see and I want to show the employees that only work on projects within their department.

I have joined three tables together and tried using the NOT IN operator but I can't seem to use it correctly?

Here is my code

```
SELECT e.FNAME,
       e.LNAME
FROM ballen15db.EMPLOYEE e,
     ballen15db.WORKS_ON w
WHERE e.SSN=w.ESSN
  AND EXISTS
    (SELECT *
     FROM ballen15db.PROJECT p
     WHERE w.PNO=p.PNUMBER
       AND p.DNUM!=e.DNO )
GROUP BY e.SSN;
```

**Expected results**

```
John Smith
Joyce English
Ramesh Rayan
Alicia Zelaya
Ahmad Jabbar
James Borg
```

**Actual Results**

```
Franklin Wong
Jennifer Wallace
```

[image]

Comment: Sample data would really help.

Comment: I think you want `NOT EXISTS` rather than `EXISTS`

Comment: I used that and returns all employees and I will upload a picture soon!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, learn to use proper `JOIN` syntax.  Then use `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` for your logic:

```
select e.SSN, e.FNAME, e.LNAME 
from ballen15db.EMPLOYEE e join
     ballen15db.WORKS_ON w
     on e.SSN = w.ESSN join
     ballen15db.PROJECT p 
     on w.PNO = p.PNUMBER 
group by e.SSN, e.FNAME, e.LNAME 
having sum(p.dum <> e.dno) = 0;
```

The `having` counts the number of times that the department numbers differ.  The `= 0` say that no such rows exist.

Comment: OMG! This was my original solution up until the group by and then decided to change it to something else!

Comment: It would be more readable had MySQL have `every` operator. Postgres has it, you can rewrite the above in Postgres as: `having every(p.dum = e.dno)`. You can make it a bit readable on MySQL by writing it as `having bit_and(p.dum = e .dno)`, hmm.. "bit readable", it's a pun :)  Read more on every: http://www.anicehumble.com/2019/04/not-every-rdbms-has-every.html

Comment: @MichaelBuen . . . I disagree.  Confusing "bits" and "booleans" is not a good thing.  Alas, MySQL does not offer `bool_and()`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Yes confusing bit and boolean is not a good thing, hence the 'a bit readable' disclaimer; if MySQL at least offers bool_and, things would be great. At least the `_and` part of the `bit_and` would easily offer a clue on what the expression is trying to express, that is an `every`. Practice using `bit_and` every time, it is every bit as good as SQL Standard's `every`, it would come off naturally as an `every` idiom the more one uses it. Unlike sum approach, sum does not come off naturally on conveying every's intent, besides, the logic need to be inverted

Comment: And also MySQL users are not confused on the affinity of boolean to int/bit, otherwise every MySQL users would write it as `sum(case when p.dum <> e.dno then 1 else 0 end) = 0`. If MySQL users feel natural that boolean can work as an int/bit, I think it also feels natural to MySQL users that int/bit can work as a boolean. bit has more affinity to expressing boolean, than with sum to expressing boolean

Comment: @MichaelBuen . . . "booleans" are treated as *integers* in a numeric context, not as bits.  That is why I use `sum()`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Likewise, "booleans" are treated as _bit_ in a bit context, hence `bit_and` is a fine choice too

Answer (score 1):

This answer is same as Gordon Linoff. `every` is included in SQL Standard. Postgres has it, MySQL don't. If MySQL has `every`, Gordon would write it as:

```
select
    e.SSN,
    e.FNAME,
    e.LNAME
from
    ballen15db.EMPLOYEE e
    join ballen15db.WORKS_ON w on e.SSN = w.ESSN
    join ballen15db.PROJECT p on w.PNO = p.PNUMBER
group by
    e.SSN,
    e.FNAME,
    e.LNAME
having
    every(p.dum = e.dno);
```

`every` is not available in MySQL. So I would write the above using MySQL's `bit_and` instead, so as to preserve the logic. No need to use a combo of inverting the logic, sum and 0.

```
select
    e.SSN,
    e.FNAME,
    e.LNAME
from
    ballen15db.EMPLOYEE e
    join ballen15db.WORKS_ON w on e.SSN = w.ESSN
    join ballen15db.PROJECT p on w.PNO = p.PNUMBER
group by
    e.SSN,
    e.FNAME,
    e.LNAME
having
    bit_and(p.dum = e.dno);
```

If your RDBMS doesn't have `every`, `bool_and` nor `bit_and`, and you want to avoid the inversion of logic (sum approach), you can use `min` instead of `sum`:

```
select
    e.SSN,
    e.FNAME,
    e.LNAME
from
    ballen15db.EMPLOYEE e
    join ballen15db.WORKS_ON w on e.SSN = w.ESSN
    join ballen15db.PROJECT p on w.PNO = p.PNUMBER
group by
    e.SSN,
    e.FNAME,
    e.LNAME
having
    min(p.dum = e.dno) = 1
```

The logic works, that if a department from employee's projects is different from employee's department, it would result to false/0, then `min` would return 0. If a department from employee's projects is same as employee's department, it would result to true/1, then if all the departments from employee's projects are same as employee's department, then `min` would return 1.

Of course, if using MySQL it's better to use `bit_and`, it has more semantic than `min` and 1 combo, due to `_and` part, and it has much more semantic than the combo of inverted logic, `sum` and 0. `bit_and` is a bit readable, pun :)

---

> But essentially the zero or one indicates Boolean values used to check if something true or not in SQL? -- B. Allen

Yes, but it's mostly due to lack of proper boolean support of those SQL databases. Most SQL databases that lacks proper boolean support, uses zero or one instead. Postgres has a proper boolean support.

In MySQL, its boolean is essentially just an [integer](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-boolean/). `tinyint(1)` to be exact. You can think of MySQL's `tinyint(1)` is leading a double life, it's both an integer and a boolean.

Though MySQL (like SQL Server) doesn't have real boolean, at least MySQL does a better job than SQL Server as MySQL allows its tinyint to act as a boolean.

So aside from being able to do this in MySQL:

```
select * from hero where hero.can_fly = 1
```

You can also do the following in MySQL, so your query now feels like natural English, which is what a language with good boolean support should provide:

```
select * from hero where hero.can_fly
```

Whereas in SQL Server you can't do `where hero.can_fly`, must do `where hero.can_fly = 1`.

Postgres' boolean will only allow the following. Postgres encourages the users to use the proper boolean expression. It also feels like expressing thought in natural language.

```
where hero.can_fly

where not hero.can_fly
```

Postgres won't allow this code to run:

```
where hero.can_fly = 1

where hero.can_fly = 0
```

On first impression, it looks like MySQL offers the most flexibility. Some would say that it's not a bug, it's a feature. However, MySQL won't flag the followings as wrong codes, let's say a user mistyped a value. MySQL will happily run the code despite the boolean expression having an invalid value.

```
where hero.can_fly = 2

where hero.can_fly = -1
```

So it's a bug.

> I also assume that min would be the minimal value returned back if the condition is true or false? -- B. Allen

Correct. On MySQL, a true expression maps to 1, a false maps to zero. So if there is at least one expression from rows that yields a false result, min would return 0. If all rows yields a true result, min would return 1.

Tests: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/spibD9EhCVKHbnyu5GjCV8/4

---

Good read:

https://blog.jooq.org/2014/12/18/a-true-sql-gem-you-didnt-know-yet-the-every-aggregate-function/

http://www.anicehumble.com/2019/04/not-every-rdbms-has-every.html

From [twitter](https://twitter.com/CompSciFact/status/1116082210107473920):

> 'Programming languages teach you not to want what they don't provide.' -- Paul Graham

However, for Postgres, it teaches its users to want other RDBMSes to provide what Postgres already provided.

Comment: Thank you for the in depth explaination! I will take a look at both articles that you provided! 
But essentially the zero or one indicates Boolean values used to check if something true or not in SQL? I never knew that actually. I also assume that min would be the minimal value returned back if the condition is true or false? @MichaelBuen